# What is the Syntax for displaying a State img Url in React?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, state

I think I have a simple question to which I haven't found an answer which would work for me.

The main idea is: Once the User uploads the image to aws s3 it would get displayed (the reading from DB still in progress, but it would work as below +/-).

Why isn't the below img not displaying in React, if I set it manually to it it works. :

```
  handleFiles = async (e) => {   
    const uploadedImage = await uploadFile(e.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({imgLink:uploadedImage})
  };

  state = {
    imgLink: "../../../images/person-01.jpg",
  };
  render() {
    .....
              <div className="bg-transfer">
                <img src={this.state.imgLink} alt="" />
              </div>
         .....
 <div className="single-file-input">
                <input
                  type="file"
                  id="user_image"
                  name="user_image"
                  onChange={this.handleFiles}
                />
```

Upload file:

```
import S3FileUpload from "react-s3";

const ID = "";
const SECRET = "";
//If bucket not set, getting 400 error.
const BUCKET_NAME = "";
//If Region not set then this isn't working, getting 400 error
const REGION_NAME = "";

const config = {
  bucketName: BUCKET_NAME,
  /*dirName: 'media', /* optional */
  region: REGION_NAME,
  accessKeyId: ID,
  secretAccessKey: SECRET,
  /*s3Url: 'https:/your-custom-s3-url.com/', /* optional */
};


export const uploadFile = async (file) => {  
  try {
    const response = await S3FileUpload.uploadFile(file, config)
    return response.location;    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

};
```

I tried to use  `imgLink: "\"../../../images/person-01.jpg\"",`, as I thought I am missing links, but it didn't work either. Since I will be reading the path from MongoDB I can't simply import the image, but would require this to be dynamically changed.

What syntax should be used here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure why I can't use the state for the img URL still, but turns out that if you take the URL from MongoDb directly and place in the HTML, it is displayed. Which is what I wanted at first.

This time the middle developing step was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`uploadedImaged` is probably not a valid url link, unless the function `uploadFile` returns the url generated for the file. You should be update the state with the url for the file generated in s3.

Comment: 1) I initiallize the state as per above don't call it from anywhere. 
2) Once I update the image file I would want to set the state with the new URL, and this should display the new file. 3) Sorry haven't added the upload function, it would be a user input.

Comment: @RaitisLebedevs, what is the return value of uploadFile?

Comment: it is the link to image which was put on aws s3. Nor by default, nor the link is working. E.g. If I would be able to display the link if I hardcode the set state it would work good.

Comment: added to the details, but this wouldn't really matter as can't display the image from the state if I hard code the value there even.